# Uniqueness for list of lists

Tags: python, unique

I am curious what would be an efficient way of uniquifying such data objects:

```
testdata =[ ['9034968', 'ETH'], ['14160113', 'ETH'], ['9034968', 'ETH'], ['11111', 'NOT'], ['9555269', 'NOT'], ['15724032', 'ETH'], ['15481740', 'ETH'], ['15481757', 'ETH'], ['15481724', 'ETH'], ['10307528', 'ETH'], ['15481757', 'ETH'], ['15481724', 'ETH'], ['15481740', 'ETH'], ['15379365', 'ETH'], ['11111', 'NOT'], ['9555269', 'NOT'], ['15379365', 'ETH']
]
```

For each data pair, left numeric string PLUS the type at the right tells the uniqueness of a data element. The return value should be a list of lists as same as the testdata, but with only the unique values kept.

Comment: you were dealing with Ether 10 years ago? Wow! How did you know about them back then!

Answer (score 169, accepted):

You can use a set:

```
unique_data = [list(x) for x in set(tuple(x) for x in testdata)]
```

You can also see [this page](http://www.peterbe.com/plog/uniqifiers-benchmark) which benchmarks a variety of methods that either preserve or don't preserve order.

Comment: Do note that you lose the ordering with this method. If it's relevant than you'll have to sort it after or remove the items manually.

Comment: I am getting an error: `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'`. Python 2.6.2, Ubuntu Jaunty.

Comment: @Hellnar: he just updated the code to use a tuple, now you won't get that problem anymore :)

Comment: @Manoj Govindan: The problem occurs because lists aren't hashable and only hashable types can be used in a set. I have fixed it by converting to tuples and then converting back to a list afterwards. Probably though the OP should be using a list of tuples.

Comment: @Khan: Python sets are unordered. That doesn't mean you won't get a consistent result from `list(some_set)` but it means that you cannot set or influence the sort order in any way. For more info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12165200/order-of-unordered-python-sets

Comment: @Wolph: Replace `set` with `dict.fromkeys`, and leave everything else the same, and on CPython/PyPy 3.6+ (or any Python 3.7+), you'll preserve order (the first copy of each duplicated value is kept in the original order, subsequent duplicates are discarded).

Answer (score 11):

I tried @Mark's answer and got an error. Converting the list and each elements into a tuple made it work. Not sure if this the best way though.

```
list(map(list, set(map(lambda i: tuple(i), testdata))))
```

Of course the same thing can be expressed using a list comprehension instead.

```
[list(i) for i in set(tuple(i) for i in testdata)]
```

I am using Python 2.6.2.

**Update**

@Mark has since changed his answer. His current answer uses tuples and will work. So will mine :)

**Update 2**

Thanks to @Mark. I have changed my answer to return a list of lists rather than a list of tuples.

Comment: Here's a little trick: instead of `lambda x: foo(x)` you can just write `foo`.

Comment: @Mark: Where `foo` is a callable. Gotcha.

Answer (score 6):

Use [`unique`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) in `numpy` to solve this:

```
import numpy as np

np.unique(np.array(testdata), axis=0)
```

Note that the `axis` keyword needs to be specified otherwise the list is first flattened.

Alternatively, use [`vstack`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.vstack.html):

```
np.vstack({tuple(row) for row in testdata})
```

Comment: This option is great because it doesn't limit you to a tuple. You can find unique list of lists of multiple attributes.

Answer (score 3):

Expanding a bit on [@Mark Byers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/61974/mark-byers) solution, you can also just do one list comprehension and typecast to get what you need:

```
testdata = list(set(tuple(x) for x in testdata))
```

Also, if you don't like list comprehensions as many find them confusing, you can do the same in a for loop:

```
for i, e in enumerate(testdata):
    testdata[i] = tuple(e)
testdata = list(set(testdata))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import sets
testdata =[ ['9034968', 'ETH'], ['14160113', 'ETH'], ['9034968', 'ETH'], ['11111', 'NOT'], ['9555269', 'NOT'], ['15724032', 'ETH'], ['15481740', 'ETH'], ['15481757', 'ETH'], ['15481724', 'ETH'], ['10307528', 'ETH'], ['15481757', 'ETH'], ['15481724', 'ETH'], ['15481740', 'ETH'], ['15379365', 'ETH'], ['11111', 'NOT'], ['9555269', 'NOT'], ['15379365', 'ETH']]
conacatData = [x[0] + x[1] for x in testdata]
print conacatData
uniqueSet = sets.Set(conacatData)
uniqueList = [ [t[0:-3], t[-3:]] for t in uniqueSet]
print uniqueList
```

Comment: Also, the sets module is deprecated, use the builtin set-type instead.

Comment: Simple Ideas work

Answer (score 1):

if you have a list of objects than you can modify @Mark Byers answer to:

```
unique_data = [list(x) for x in set(tuple(x.testList) for x in testdata)]
```

where testdata is a list of objects which has a list testList as attribute.

Answer (score 1):

I was about to post my own take on this until I noticed that @pyfunc had already come up with something similar. I'll post my take on this problem anyway in case it's helpful.

```
testdata =[ ['9034968', 'ETH'], ['14160113', 'ETH'], ['9034968', 'ETH'], ['11111', 'NOT'], ['9555269', 'NOT'], ['15724032', 'ETH'], ['15481740', 'ETH'], ['15481757', 'ETH'], ['15481724', 'ETH'], ['10307528', 'ETH'], ['15481757', 'ETH'], ['15481724', 'ETH'], ['15481740', 'ETH'], ['15379365', 'ETH'], ['11111', 'NOT'], ['9555269', 'NOT'], ['15379365', 'ETH']
]
flatdata = [p[0] + "%" + p[1] for p in testdata]
flatdata = list(set(flatdata))
testdata = [p.split("%") for p in flatdata]
print(testdata)
```

Basically, you concatenate each element of your list into a single string using a list comprehension, so that you have a list of single strings. This is then much easier to turn into a set, which makes it unique. Then you simply split it on the other end and convert it back to your original list.

I don't know how this compares in terms of performance but it's a simple and easy-to-understand solution I think.