# Hashing a tuple in Python where order matters?

Tags: python

I have:

```
tuple1 = token1, token2
tuple2 = token2, token1
for tuple in [tuple1, tuple2]:
    if tuple in dict:
        dict[tuple] += 1
    else:
        dict[tuple] = 1
```

However, both tuple 1 and tuple2 are getting the same counts. What is a way to hash a group of 2 things such that order matters?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Order is taken into account when hashing:

```
>>> hash((1,2))
1299869600
>>> hash((2,1))
1499606158
```

This assumes that the objects themselves have unique hashes.  Even if they don't, you could still be OK when using it in a dictionary (as long as the objects themselves aren't equal as defined by their `__eq__` method):

```
>>> t1 = 'a',hash('a') 
>>> [hash(x) for x in t1]  #both elements in the tuple have same hash value since `int` hash to themselves in cpython
[-468864544, -468864544]
>>> t2 = hash('a'),'a'
>>> hash(t1)
1486610051
>>> hash(t2)
1486610051
>>> d = {t1:1,t2:2}  #This is OK.  dict's don't fail when there is a hash collision
>>> d
{('a', -468864544): 1, (-468864544, 'a'): 2}
>>> d[t1]+=7
>>> d[t1]
8
>>> d[t1]+=7
>>> d[t1]
15
>>> d[t2]   #didn't touch d[t2] as expected.
2
```

Note that due to hash collisions, this dict is likely to be less efficient than another dict where there aren't hash collisions :)

Comment: Assuming `token1` and `token2` `hash()` to different values themselves, of course.

Comment: @sr2222 -- Yes, of course, but I suppose it is worth documenting that as you can override `__hash__` on a class in such a way to make order irrelevant when you have a tuple containing instances of that class ... but even then, depending on how `__eq__` was implemented, your `dict` could still come out OK (although really inefficient due to hash collisions).

Comment: @sr2222 -- I've updated my answer further because of your comment.  It was fun for me and I thought you might find it interesting.

Comment: That is interesting.  I need to reread the docs on the internal workings of dicts...

Comment: @sr2222 -- I learned *a lot* when I watched the video that I reposted [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12165200/order-of-unordered-python-sets/12165239#12165239)

Answer (score 7):

The reason they are getting the same count is that your code explicitly increments both `token1,token2` and `token2,token1` counts at the same time. If you don't, the counts won't stay in lockstep:

```
In [16]: import collections

In [17]: d = collections.defaultdict(int)

In [18]: d[1,2] += 1

In [19]: d[1,2]
Out[19]: 1

In [20]: d[2,1]
Out[20]: 0
```

Comment: I think that I would usually write this as `d[(1,2)]` rather than `d[1,2]` even though they are equivalent ...

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have posted one instance of the body of a loop. Might I suggest that you use  [`collections.Counter`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) for what you are trying to do, which does exactly what you want, but in one line:

```
counter = (collections.Counter(myListOfTuples) + 
           collections.Counter([j,i for i,j in myListOfTuples]))
```