# single_source_shortest_path : criterion in case of multiple shortest paths?

Tags: python, networkx

In case more than one shortest path between two nodes is available, which is the criterion used by single_source_shortest_path to pick one path?

Answer (score 1):

There is none. Since it traverses the graph with a `BFS`ish approach, and the order it visits a node's neighbors, is determined by a [for loop](https://github.com/networkx/networkx/blob/master/networkx/algorithms/shortest_paths/unweighted.py#L248), and that has an [arbitrary order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14445667/what-is-the-order-of-looping-for-loop-in-python-dictionary).

Comment: I have been making some tests: is it possible that the order is determined by the alphabetic sort of the node indexes? It seems to be a rather consistent behaviour, even if the indexes are explicitly declared as numbers, they are treated as strings.

Comment: read the third answer and the comments of the second answer of linked question.