# Are the integer keys in a Python dictionary sorted and sorted with priority?

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm using python 2.7.5 on OS X Mavericks and I'm seeing unexpected behavior with a dictionary I'm using to generate a simple text menu. My question is: **are the integer keys in a Python dictionary sorted and sorted with priority?**  I can see that the `mainMenu_1` dictionary (containing some numeric keys and some string keys) sorts the integer keys and then presents the string keys in the expected random order. `mainMenu_2` is randomized as expected.

from the python 2.7.8 docs:

> "It is best to think of a dictionary as an unordered set of key: value
>   pairs, with the requirement that the keys are unique (within one
>   dictionary)."

```
mainMenu_1 = {
   0: 'README',
   1: 'New Set',
   2: 'View Sets',
   3: 'Quiz',
   4: 'Scores',
   5: 'Configuration Settings',
   'Q': 'Quit',
   'a': 'additional letter to test',
   'b': 'additional letter to test'
}

mainMenu_2 = {
   'one': 'README',
   'two': 'New Set',
   'three': 'View Sets',
   'four': 'Quiz',
   'five': 'Scores',
   'six': 'Configuration Settings',
   'Q': 'Quit',
   'd': 'another letter to test'
}

print mainMenu_1.keys()
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 'a', 'Q', 'b']
print mainMenu_2.keys()
['four', 'Q', 'five', 'three', 'd', 'six', 'two', 'one']
```

And a third test:

```
c = {1:'one','two':'two',3:'three'}
print c
{1: 'one', 3: 'three', 'two': 'two'}
```

Comment: For a hint, look at the `hash()` of a few integers.

Comment: Python auto hashes the dictionary inorder to reduce the time order complexity of lookup

Comment: There's no guarantee that a dictionary will be ordered. If you want that behavior, use an OrderedDict.

Comment: If you want a more detailed explanation of how python stores key/value pairs, have a look at this article : http://www.laurentluce.com/posts/python-dictionary-implementation/

Comment: What does "sorted with priority" mean?

Comment: Ned, at the time, I meant that integer keys seemed to be come first when you print or iterate through the dict, and in a sorted order.  I can see that this isn't the case now.

Comment: Very related:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12165200/order-of-unordered-python-sets

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`dict`s are "sorted" (quotation fingers heavily used) according to their underlying hash table buckets.  The `hash()` of an integer is itself:

```
hash(42)
Out[29]: 42
```

...but that doesn't necessarily mean that lower integers will appear before higher ones since the hash is taken *modulo table size* in order to allocate it to a bucket.

```
d = {i:i for i in range(250,260)}

print(d)
{256: 256, 257: 257, 258: 258, 259: 259, 250: 250, 251: 251, 252: 252, 253: 253, 254: 254, 255: 255}
```

So contiguous integers are not necessarily sorted in a `dict`.  And as for integers getting *priority*, no, there's nothing special about integers.  Their hash values just clump together particularly well, and you happened to pick some strings that hashed larger (again, modulo table size) than that clump.

```
hash('roippi')
Out[26]: 8915818834981308633

hash('roippi') % 8 # min hashtable size in py2 is 3-bit
Out[27]: 1

d = {0:'', 'roippi':0, 2:0}

print(d)
{0: '', 'roippi': 0, 2: 0}
```

All of this is of course an implementation detail of cPython, so the only thing that is guaranteed is that ordering is "arbitrary but consistent<sup>1</sup>".

<sup>1</sup>consistent, at least, across a single run of the python interpreter.  3.2.3+ [randomly seeds the hash](https://docs.python.org/3.5/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONHASHSEED) of certain (non-int) types, and earlier versions will also do so if run with the [-R flag](https://docs.python.org/3.5/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-R).

Comment: Consider if this answer need to be updated for "preserves order" behavior of Python 3.6+

Answer (score 2):

According to some simple tests I have just executed, it is indeed like you say - and I was testing it in **Python 3.4.0**

I don't know the reason for which that happens. I see no reason though to think of

> "It is best to think of a dictionary as an unordered set of key: value pairs, with the requirement that the keys are unique (within one dictionary)."

as misleading or untrue in any way. This is perfectly right: even though we can see there's some sorting going on behind the scenes, you **should never rely on it**. That's why the docs say what they say. They **could just as well sort integer keys backwards and nobody should care** - your implementations cannot rely on that mechanism.

That said - still a nice find!