# Why does a set of numbers appear to be sorted?

Tags: python, set, python-3.4

Running this code multiple times

```
t = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'}
print(t)
```

could print something like:

```
{'c', 'b', 'a', 'd'} 
{'d', 'b', 'c', 'a'} # different
{'d', 'b', 'c', 'a'} # same
{'a', 'd', 'b', 'c'} # different
{'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'} # different
# etc
```

(If you are using the console to replicate it, make sure you click <kbd>Rerun</kbd> every time before you re-paste the code and execute it. If you still can't replicate, perhaps you have [hash randomization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27522626/hash-function-in-python-3-3-returns-different-results-between-sessions/27522708#27522708) not equal to `random`. [On Python 3.3 and greater, hash randomization is turned on by default.](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-R))

---

On the other hand, the code below always prints the same set, and it's actually sorted:

```
s = {1, 6, 3.3, 4}
print(s) 

# prints: 
# {1, 3.3, 4, 6}
# {1, 3.3, 4, 6}
# {1, 3.3, 4, 6}
# {1, 3.3, 4, 6}
```

**Question:**
Why do sets of numbers appear to be always sorted and are they really *always* sorted?

Comment: Note that a `set` is basically just a `dict` with no values.

Comment: It only seems to be sorted in the iPython console, not in the normal python console, when iterating through it or calling `str(s)` or `repr(s)`.

Comment: Another possible duplicate:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12165200/order-of-unordered-python-sets

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note, I don't have python3.4 handy, but on python2.7 this isn't always the case (and I'd expect that to be true of python3.4 too).

I can even change the order of the elements based on how I put them into the set:

```
>>> print({1, 9})
set([9, 1])
>>> print({9, 1})
set([1, 9])
>>> set([9, 1])
set([9, 1])
>>> set([1, 9])
set([1, 9])
```

The order is determined by the hash of the element and by when it was inserted (in the case of hash collisions).  In CPython, integers hash to themselves and a dict/set has 8 slots free to start with.  Since there are 8 spots available, we can hash numbers 0 -> 7 (inclusive) without a hash collision.  However, if we try to hash 8 and 0 (or 9 and 1) in the same set, we'll get a collision.  if `9` is already in the set and then we try to put `1` in, python looks and says "Oh snap, that slot's taken -- Now I need to put it in the next most favorable slot".  The details of collision resolution are beyond what I've looked into, so I can't offer insight into what slot that is ...

Note if we had more than ~5 elements in the set, then it would be resized (IIRC, to 16, then 32, then 64, ...) which changes which elements would collide (naturally).

Comment: Not printing will give you a different ordering

Comment: @PadraicCunningham -- Not sure what you mean?  if I do `a = {1, 9}; a` I still get the same thing as `print({1, 9})` on python2.7

Comment: http://pastebin.com/yaaS9UbE, that is running from ipython which seems to be different to the python repl

Comment: @PadraicCunningham -- You're using IPython which appears to try to be helpful and sort the elements for you.  What happens if you just print `repr(s)` (which is what the normal python REPL will do)?

Comment: funnily just using print or print repr both show the repr output i.e `set([3.3, 1, 6, 9])`, just doing `s` actually shows the nicely sorted order.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham -- Yep, that's what I'd expect.  `IPython` can intercept the `s` and see that it's a set and print it in sorted order wheras if there's a function call or statement in the middle, it can't.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham -- The really surprising thing for me is that `{1, 9}` and `set([1, 9])` give different results... For some reason it seems that python sets that involve only literals are read backwards?

Comment: `s = set([1, 9]) s -> {1, 9}, print s -> set([1, 9])` and `s = {1, 9} s -> {1, 9},
print s -> set([9, 1])`

Comment: To see all the examples where the set order is not the same as the sorted order: https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM9ZNBtP//6flFylkKmTmKRQl5qWnahgaaFpxcYIEs9AFOTPTFIrzi0pSUzSqM3UUsmo1FRRtFXIyi0tgfJAizoKizLwSDZCA5v//AA