# python set element sequence

Tags: python, set

```
>>> x = {"a","b","c","d","e"}
>>> print x
set(['a', 'c', 'b', 'e', 'd'])
```

Who can help to explain why the sequence of set elements changed after it is printed out?

-- Update:
Thanks guys!

Yes, set is a set of elements, there is no order for "set".
but every time you print, the output is the same.
Please help explain why the set {"a","b","c","d","e"} was saved as ['a', 'c', 'b', 'e', 'd'] by python, in what kind of order? it seems not in the sequence of ASCII of characters.

-- Update:
Paul Rooney's answer is the root cause I want to know. The order of set output relates to the hash of each element in the set which is explained in the official document. Thanks!

> The order is dictated by the hashes of the values, the size of the underlying hash table and the number of hash collisions that occurred. See here  --Paul Rooney

Comment: Set, inherently, has no **order**. What is it that you want to do exactly?

Comment: The order is dictated by the hashes of the values, the size of the underlying hash table and the number of hash collisions that occurred. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12165200/order-of-unordered-python-sets)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

check this out: https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set

sets simply do not have any ordering to them.

Comment: That's the wrong documentation. The `sets` module has nothing to do with the `set` type. As the big red notice at the top of the page says, `sets` is deprecated and `set` is its replacement.

Comment: good call. I updated the link

Comment: Better. I recommend linking to [a bit further up the page](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset); right now, your link goes to below the part where the documentation says sets are unordered.

Answer (score 3):

It's not after the `print` but after the cast to `set` that the order is lost.

The *set* datatype is a unique, unordered list.