# Confused about the output from set() in Python(2.4.3)

Tags: python, set

I am a beginner in python and I am using python 2.4.3.

I have a question regarding to the order resulted from the `set()`function.

I understand `set()` will remove the the duplicate elements from a string and

> [class set([iterable])
>
> Return a new set object, optionally with elements taken from iterable.][1](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#func-set)

But for example, when I do the following

```
a='abcdabcd' 
set(a)
```

it returned a result of

```
set(['a','c','b','d'])
```

in stead of

```
set(['a','b','c','d'])
```

which I would actually expect.

Why is that? I am not able to understand how the output was generated.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: *sets — Unordered collections of unique elements*

Comment: Why on earth are you using 2.4.3?

Comment: Also possibly relevant:  http://stackoverflow.com/q/12165200/748858

Comment: any referral documentation regarding the "unordered collection"?

Comment: @Meruemu -- Have a look [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html#module-sets)  (Notice the banner title).  Admittedly, that's for python2.7, but it still applies to python2.4

Comment: for those who wondering, there are many universities use historical systems...and software never updates...

Comment: @Meruemu, well if you want to learn python I would recommend getting a newer version to play with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `set` is defined as an "unordered collection of unique elements" (see [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html)). The set object in Python make no guarantees about ordering, and you should not expect nor rely on the order to stay the same.

Comment: I think that this is _mostly_ correct, but it does make one (sometimes useful) guarantee about the order -- specifically, multiple iterations over the same set will yield items in the same order provided that you haven't added or removed any items.