# Replace duplicates in a list column

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, list

I got a list, in one (the last) column is a string of comma separated items:

```
temp = ['AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC-DDD', 'EE,FFF,FFF,EE']
```

Now I want to remove the duplicates in that column.

I tried to make a list out of every column:

```
    e = [s.split(',') for s in temp]
    print e
```

Which gave me:

```
[['AAA'], ['BBB'], ['CCC-DDD'], ['EE', 'FFF', 'FFF', 'EE']]
```

Now I tried to remove the duplicates with:

```
    y = list(set(e))
    print y
```

What ended up in an error

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

I'd appreciate any help.

**Edit**:

I didn't exactly said what the end result should be. The list should look like that

```
temp = ['AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC-DDD', 'EE', 'FFF']
```

Just the duplicates should get removed in the last column.

Comment: you need `e = [list(set(x) for x in e]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apply `set` on the *elements* of the list not on the list of lists. You want your `set` to contain the strings of each list, not the lists.

```
e = [list(set(x)) for x in e]
```

You can do it directly as well:

```
e = [list(set(s.split(','))) for s in temp]

>>> e
[['AAA'], ['BBB'], ['CCC-DDD'], ['EE', 'FFF']]
```

you may want `sorted(set(s.split(',')))` instead to ensure lexicographic order (sets aren't ordered, [even in python 3.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45581901/are-sets-ordered-like-dicts-in-python3-6))

for a flat, ordered list, create a flat set comprehension and sort it:

```
e = sorted({x for s in temp for x in s.split(',')})
```

result:

```
['AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC-DDD', 'EE', 'FFF']
```

Comment: Actually don't need lists in a list at all. Is there a way to apply the set and remove the duplicates without list in list?

Answer (score 0):

Here is solution, that uses [itertools.chain](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) method

```
import itertools

temp = ['AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC-DDD', 'EE,FFF,FFF,EE']
y = list(set(itertools.chain(*[s.split(',') for s in temp])))
# ['EE', 'FFF', 'AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC-DDD']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 a = ['AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC-DDD', 'EE,FFF,FFF,EE']
 b = [s.split(',') for s in a]
 c = []
 for i in b:
     c = c + i
 c = list(set(c))

 ['EE', 'FFF', 'AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC-DDD']
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a pure functional way to do it in Python:

```
from functools import partial

split = partial(str.split, sep=',')

list(map(list, map(set, (map(split, temp)))))
[['AAA'], ['BBB'], ['CCC-DDD'], ['EE', 'FFF']]
```

Or as I see the answer doesn't need lists inside of a list:

```
from itertools import chain

list(chain(*map(set, (map(split, temp)))))
['AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC-DDD', 'EE', 'FFF']
```