# Why does list(set([2,1,3,6,5,3,6,4])) automatically order the list?

Tags: python, list, sorting, set

I was experimenting with `set` in python and while I understood that it is [unsorted, based on hashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12165200/order-of-unordered-python-sets), I find it strange that it automatically sorts these numbers, both in Python 2 and in 3:

```python
>>> list(set([2,1,3,6,5,3,6,4]))
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
>>> list(set([2,1,3,6,5,3,6,4,0,7]))
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

I googled for some time but didn't find the answer to the behavior of these two functions combined.

Comment: Likely just the way the hash buckets line up.

Comment: Yeah I guess that is entirely based on likelihood and it is just a bizarre coincidence

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It does not, here is an example

```
In [2]: list(set([1,9,5,10]))                                                                                                                                                                                                
Out[2]: [1, 10, 5, 9]
```

Also, from the docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset

> A set object is an unordered collection of distinct hashable objects.

The reason sometimes you see the sorted output is dependent on how the `hash` is computed, and sometimes on what REPL is being used, and this behaviour is well described in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45581901/are-sets-ordered-like-dicts-in-python3-6)

Example for `ipython`, the way the set is printed, changes when we enable [doctest_mode](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#magic-doctest_mode), which disables `pretty-printing` of `ipython`

```
In [1]: set([1,6,8,4])                                                                                                                                                                                                       
Out[1]: {1, 4, 6, 8}

In [2]: %doctest_mode                                                                                                                                                                                                        
Exception reporting mode: Plain
Doctest mode is: ON
>>> set([1,6,8,4])                                                                                                                                                                                                           
{8, 1, 4, 6}
```

Comment: Strange, yet if I add more numbers, it does: `list(set([2,1,3,6,5,3,6,4,0,7,10,9]))` -> `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10]`

Comment: If the implementation uses a binary tree or similar data structure, rather than a hash table, then the results will be ordered. But you should not assume that to be the case since the documentation explicitly says it is not ordered.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a feature of sets and only a coincidence stemming from how sets are created.
The hash of the items in your list are the numbers themselves. So under **some** circumstances the created set will show this behaviour but is in no way reliable.
Looking at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45581901/are-sets-ordered-like-dicts-in-python3-6) you can read more about it.