# How i can get correct result through f-strings

Tags: python, f-string

```
print(f"{ {x ** 2 if (x**2) <= 10 else x ** 3 for x in range(5)} }")
```

gives result :

```
{0, 1, **64**, 4, 9}
```

Why 64 is on this place when its should be on the last?

But

```
print([x ** 2 if (x ** 2) <= 10 else x ** 3 for x in range(5)])
```

gives correct result:

```
[0, 1, 4, 9, 64]
```

Someone explain me what i do wrong

Comment: because you are creating a set by using { } instead of [ ], and sets don't have an order. If you want the elements to have an order you should create a list like you do in the second code: `print(f"{[x ** 2 if (x**2) <= 10 else x ** 3 for x in range(5)]}")`

Comment: `sets` are unordered.. you cannot expect any position to be fixed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why don't Python sets preserve insertion order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61414947/why-dont-python-sets-preserve-insertion-order)

Comment: The f-string is a red herring here.

Answer (score 3):

In the following code:

```
print(f"{ {x ** 2 if (x**2) <= 10 else x ** 3 for x in range(5)} }")
```

you have used a [set](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_sets.asp). Sets are unordered which means that each time you print the set, you will get the values at different positions. Set elements cannot be referenced through indexes. Sets are defined using curly brackets { }.

On the other hand, this code:

```
print([x ** 2 if (x ** 2) <= 10 else x ** 3 for x in range(5)])
```

uses a [list](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists.asp). Lists are ordered, so, if you print a list, you will get the elements in the correct order every time. List elements can be referenced through their indexes. Lists are defined using square brackets [ ].

This has nothing to do with f-strings.