# Please help me with understanding how to order sets/lists

Tags: python

```
biology = ["Sarah", "Ahmed", "Fred", "Gillian", "Shradah", "Max", "Max", "Sara", "Max", "Esther"]

computerScience = ["Sarah", "John", "Fred", "Gillian", "Jermaine", "Max", "Sara", "Juan", "Esther"]

english = ["Nico", "Sharjeel", "Isabella", "Taylor", "Ali", "Ali", "Jean-Baptiste", "Jean-Baptiste", "Jean-Baptiste", "William"]


setThing=set()
for word in biology:
  setThing.add(word)

listThing=[]

for word in setThing:
  listThing.append(word)

print(listThing)
```

In this, I am trying to take the list called biology and put it in a set so that it gets rid of the repeats. I am trying to turn it back into a list that has the same order of names as the list: biology. But when I turned it into a set, the order of the names completely changed. Is there any way I could use some kind of function to order either the new set or the new list so that the names are in the same order as the original "biology" list?

Comment: sets are not ordered, unlike dicts: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45581901/are-sets-ordered-like-dicts-in-python3-6

Comment: have a look at `unique_everseen` in the [itertools recipes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html?highlight=unique_everseen#itertools-recipes).

Comment: You can use: `[lst[i] for i in set([lst.index(i) for i in lst])]` - where `lst` is `biology`. This basically creates a list of indexes and populates the new list based on the item's index in the old list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
biology  = list(dict.fromkeys(biology))
```

This will remove duplicates in order and return the unique elements in a list

Comment: Note: This only works for Python 3.7+.