# Why iter() sorts in place a set in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, set

Calling `iter()` on a set in Python seems to sort the set in place.

Example:

```py
>>> my_set = {2, 1, 3}
>>> _ = iter(my_set)
>>> my_set
{1, 2, 3}
```

I am wondering why is that's the case. I guess it has something to do with the way `__iter__` or `__next__` are implemented for `set` in cPython but I am not sure.

Any idea is welcome.

---

**EDIT**

As pointed by answers and comments below, the `_ = iter(my_set)` does not change the results - `my_set` prints 'ordered'. The reasons are explained in details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12165239/2476009).

Comment: And what do you get if you eliminate the `_ = iter(my_set)`?

Comment: `iter` has nothing to do with it, I achieve the same result with `new_set={2,1,3};new_set` which outputs `{1, 2, 3}`. I would imagine it's more to do with how a (unordered) set is built in the first place

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45589593/6273251) for what seems like a decent explanation; specifically, the part about "well-defined hash order". It's not actually getting sorted at all. There's no guarantee of order whatsoever, but a set of numbers can happen to look sorted, it seems. They give an example of a set where it does not get "sorted" - `{6,7,8,9}` prints as `{8, 9, 6, 7}`

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12165200/order-of-unordered-python-sets

Comment: The order of items within a set should be considered as unreliable and, indeed, irrelevant. As to your specific question... there is no way that *iter()* would modify the value(s) referred to by its first parameter. Consider the implications if it did!

Comment: @PM77-1: thank you very much for the link, super useful !

Comment: @RandomDavis: Thank you very much for the link !

Answer (score 2):

without the `_ = iter(my_set)` the result is sorted also

```python
>>> my_set = {2, 1, 3}
>>> my_set
{1, 2, 3}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sets are unordered, which means they can appear in different orders when you call them. See more here: https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_sets.asp

Answer (score 1):

As stated by @S4eed3sm, using the `{}` creates a set which becomes **unordered**. However, that's not the point of the iterator.

By using an iterator, you can call the `next()` method on the iterator to get the next item in the iterator. That's the purpose of the iterator, not sorting the set.

In case you want to sort a list, for example, you can use the `sorted()` method which is also built-in in python.