# Order of elements returned by set

Tags: python, list, set

So I was converting a list with repetitive elements into a set to have each element appear once. I know that sets are unordered so they will display the elements in the order given. I ran the below script and I noticed a strange output.

```
mylist = [1,2,2,33,4,4,11,22,3,3,2]

print(set(mylist))
```

The output would be:

`{1, 2, 33, 4, 3, 11, 22}`

The 3 in the original list appears after the 11 and 22, so why does it appear before them in the set?

Comment: It depends on how typecasting is performed by python. Seems like converting to a set appends new elements at the end while rejecting one that exists in set.

Comment: `..so they will display the elements in the order given.` - what makes you think that?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12165200/order-of-unordered-python-sets

Comment: Also, cannot reproduce.

Answer (score 3):

Sets in Python do not have an order

> A set object is an unordered collection of distinct hashable objects.
>   Common uses include membership testing, removing duplicates from a
>   sequence, and computing mathematical operations such as intersection,
>   union, difference, and symmetric difference.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset