# How to prevent Python dictionary key ordering reversal?

Tags: python, dictionary, key

I have the following python code snippet involving dictionary,

```py
    sample_dict = {
        "name": "Kelly",
        "age": 25,
        "salary": 8000,
        "city": "New york"
    }
    keys = ["name", "salary"]
    sample_dict = {k: sample_dict[k] for k in sample_dict.keys() - keys}
    print(sample_dict)
```

Why the output is `{'city': 'New york', 'age': 25}` and not `{'age': 25, 'city': 'New york'}`?

What causes the reverse ordering of dictionary keys? Any help will be highly appreciated. I executed the code on Spyder and Python 3.8.5 version.

Answer (score 2):

I guess the order is lost during processing of `-` between your keys() and your `keys` list (because it involves conversion to sets which are unordered). You can build your comprehension as follow to prevent it.

```
keys = {"name", "salary"}
sample_dict = {k: sample_dict[k] for k in sample_dict.keys() if k not in keys}
```

Comment: Yes removing the - sign indeed prevents changing the order. But i was actually looking for a justification for what is actually causing the order change.

Comment: Seen your updated answer, thanks.

Comment: Also why does the  - sign between the keys converts the keys to set?

Comment: `-` calls the [difference](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/sets/difference.html) between two sets. The conversion to sets occurs implicitly as is often the case in Python. See also https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html

Answer (score 1):

@Tranbi has provided the solution to the OP. I just supplement some materials.

Although [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesmapping) preserves insertion order since 3.7.

> Changed in version 3.7: Dictionary order is guaranteed to be insertion order. This behavior was an implementation detail of CPython from 3.6.

[`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset) does not.

> Being an unordered collection, sets do not record element position or order of insertion.

If you check the result of `sample_dict.keys() - keys`, you will find it is a `set`.

```py
remain_keys = sample_dict.keys() - keys
print(type(remain_keys))
# set
for k in remain_keys:
    print(k)
# city
# age
```

Because `dict.keys()` returns a [set-like view](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects).

> Keys views are set-like since their entries are unique and hashable. ... For set-like views, all of the operations defined for the abstract base class collections.abc.Set are available (for example, ==, <, or ^).

Comment: But thats not even in alphabetical order. How the ordering is decided for remain_keys ?

Comment: @aleph, I **guess** it's related to `hash` function, collision, etc. If you iterate over `s1 = set(["age", "city"])` and `s2 = set(["city", "age"])`, you will get the different results. I tried to find a reasonable explanation, but I failed. You can open a new question for that. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12165200/order-of-unordered-python-sets) may give you some insight.

Comment: @aleph, do not expect the order of a `set`, it's **arbitrary**. Therefore, it's meaningless to attention the order of a set. This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15479974) reveals more details.