# Difference in output between dictionary comprehension and print statement

Tags: python, ipython

Earlier I was doing an exercise for a class and I noticed difference in outputs for two snippets of code that I believe would return the same output. I used iPython on a Jupyter Notebook to find my results.

The code:

`{i**3 for i in range(1,10)}`

> {1, 8, 27, 64, 125, 216, 343, 512, 729}

`print({i**3 for i in range(1,10)})`

> {64, 1, 512, 8, 343, 216, 729, 27, 125}

Can someone explain to me why they return different results?

I tried both versions of the problem, expected the exact same output. However, I got different outputs.

Comment: Generally a set object is free to store and present its items in any order (even independent from other set objects with equal items).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12165200/order-of-unordered-python-sets
Here's the answer.
Basically python hashes the data and stores it in memory. The operations then happen in the order in which they are stored. And since the data is supposed to be unordered, it's up to python how to go about storing the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Sets in Python](https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset) do not keep the order you have created them with:

> A *set* object is an unordered collection of distinct hashable objects.

So at every run the output order could be different (but does not have to be different). At every change, e.g. adding or removing items, the output order might also change.

Test program to show the change of order after adding items to a set:

```
s = set()
for i in "abcde":
  s.add(i)
  print(s)
```

First run:

```
{'a'}
{'a', 'b'}
{'a', 'b', 'c'}
{'a', 'b', 'd', 'c'}
{'a', 'e', 'c', 'b', 'd'}
```

Second run:

```
{'a'}
{'a', 'b'}
{'c', 'a', 'b'}
{'d', 'c', 'a', 'b'}
{'d', 'c', 'b', 'e', 'a'}
```

Comment: My testing shows that the `ipython display` function is sorting the set values for display purposes.

Answer (score 0):

A set { } stores unordered values unlike lists [ ].

I'm not too sure what you are using to view the content of the first snippet of code `{i**3 for i in range(1,10)}`, unless you are printing this too.

By any chance, are these being interpreted on two different versions of python? i.e. Are they both using iPython on a Jupyter Notebook?

Comment: They are both using iPython on a Jupyter Notebook.

Answer (score 0):

In a `jupyter qtconsole`:

create the set:

```
In [63]: x={i**3 for i in range(1,10)}

In [64]: print(x)
{64, 1, 512, 8, 343, 216, 729, 27, 125}

In [65]: display(x)
{1, 8, 27, 64, 125, 216, 343, 512, 729}
```

`print` shows the `str` of the object, 'barebones' use `display` of the `repr`.  It looks like `ipython's` `display` is taking the extra step of sorting the set values.

The print function shows the 'unordered' values, as 'collected' by the hashing.

Ipython `display` (the default in the ipython REPL) is a complex function, the details of which we can usually ignore.  The result is just pretty and useful.

With numpy arrays the repr/display is different in content from the str/print:

```
In [75]: a=np.arange(10, dtype='int16')

In [76]: a
Out[76]: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], dtype=int16)

In [77]: print(a)
[0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
```