# The difference between set definitions in Python

Tags: python, set, hashtable

Let us consider the following four ways to define a set in python, which will contain the elements of an iterable `l`, the elements of which are `l_1, l_2, l_3, ..., l_n`:

Method 1:

```py
def defset(l):
    x = set()
    x.update(l)
    return x
```

Method 2:

```py
set(l)
```

Method 3:

```py
{i for i in l}
```

Method 4:

```py
{l_1, l_2, l_3,..., l_n}
```

The first 3 methods give identical results, but the fourth one doesn't, for some reason.

For example, if I do this:

```py
s1 = defset([1,2,3,11]
s2 = set([1,2,3,11])
s3 = {i for i in [1,2,3,11]}
s4 = {1,2,3,11}

print(s1, s2, s3, s4, sep = "\n")
```

The output is:

```
{11,1,2,3}
{11,1,2,3}
{11,1,2,3}
{3,1,2,11}
```

So why is it that the fourth method gives a set that is different from the sets obtained by the other methods? I know that in the context of sets, all four sets are equal to each other, but a difference arises in the implementation, which changes the order in which the elements are stored in the internal hash table, right?

Why does this difference arise?

#### Edit

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12165200) does not answer my question. I've already watched [The Mighty Dictionary](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oMyy4Sm0uBs) and the follow-up talk [The Dictionary Even Mightier](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=66P5FMkWoVU) regarding how dictionaries store data in the form of a hash table. I'm aware that sets do something similar, and that based the 'order' in the hash table, they iterate over/display their elements.

I mean to ask why defining a set through these seemingly identical and equivalent methods results in the data being stored differently (internally, in the corresponding hash table).

Comment: `set` doesn't guarantee order.

Comment: @Guy That's irrelevant to the question I'm asking, the order is still consistent and the first three methods give the same order.

Comment: Why is it irrelevant? the same order is a coincidence. You will see different results in a larger numbers set.

Comment: @Guy Why is it a coincidence? Different results in large sets will appear just cus there will be more hash collisions in a larger hash table, isn't it? The order in which the `print()` function will display the elements, or the order in which `iter()` and `next()` will go over the elements is still based on the order in which the internal hash table stores the data, right? Based on an increasing order of the bit-masked hashes, that is.

Comment: Yes, but you cannot rely on the order of a set. A set is like a bag where you have only one element of each type. When you pick an element of the bag, you cannot assume it will be añin any order, you only know that there will be only one element of that type

Comment: @Elerium I completely understand that. I'm not planning on relying on the "order" of a set in any programs I make. I'm just curious about what's going on internally.

Comment: Your question is closed as a duplicate. Check the link of the duplicate to learn about how python determines the order

Comment: @Elerium I've seen the question and I honestly don't see how my question is a duplicate. The answers to that question don't answer my question. I've edited my question in an attempt to clarify how it isn't a duplicate...

Comment: All the sets are requivalent, by the definition of a  set. You can compare them with `==` to find out.

Comment: Your example is too limited. I ran your code, but using `1,2,3,11,5` as input for each of the four methods. The output I obtained was four identical lines of `{1, 2, 3, 5, 11}` (please try yourself).

Answer (score 0):

Because the order isn't guaranteed, the answer is likely to differ for different Python implementations, different versions of the same implementation, different computers, different invocations on the same computer, and so on.

Given that, [`dis`](https://docs.python.org/3.12/library/dis.html) can still shed some light on your particular version. Here is what it does for me:

```
Python 3.12.0 (tags/v3.12.0:0fb18b0, Oct  2 2023, 13:03:39) [MSC v.1935 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> dis.dis('''s1 = defset([1,2,3,11])
... s2 = set([1,2,3,11])
... s3 = {i for i in [1,2,3,11]}
... s4 = {1,2,3,11}
... ''')
  0           0 RESUME                   0

  1           2 PUSH_NULL
              4 LOAD_NAME                0 (defset)
              6 BUILD_LIST               0
              8 LOAD_CONST               0 ((1, 2, 3, 11))
             10 LIST_EXTEND              1
             12 CALL                     1
             20 STORE_NAME               1 (s1)

  2          22 PUSH_NULL
             24 LOAD_NAME                2 (set)
             26 BUILD_LIST               0
             28 LOAD_CONST               0 ((1, 2, 3, 11))
             30 LIST_EXTEND              1
             32 CALL                     1
             40 STORE_NAME               3 (s2)

  3          42 LOAD_CONST               0 ((1, 2, 3, 11))
             44 GET_ITER
             46 LOAD_FAST_AND_CLEAR      0 (i)
             48 SWAP                     2
             50 BUILD_SET                0
             52 SWAP                     2
        >>   54 FOR_ITER                 4 (to 66)
             58 STORE_FAST               0 (i)
             60 LOAD_FAST                0 (i)
             62 SET_ADD                  2
             64 JUMP_BACKWARD            6 (to 54)
        >>   66 END_FOR
             68 SWAP                     2
             70 STORE_FAST               0 (i)
             72 STORE_NAME               4 (s3)

  4          74 BUILD_SET                0
             76 LOAD_CONST               1 (frozenset({3, 1, 2, 11}))
             78 SET_UPDATE               1
             80 STORE_NAME               5 (s4)
             82 RETURN_CONST             2 (None)
        >>   84 SWAP                     2
             86 POP_TOP
```

The first three all start out by loading a constant value built into the compiled code: `(1, 2, 3, 11)`

The last one starts out different: it loads a different constant value: `frozenset({3, 1, 2, 11})`.

What then happens is fairly similar for all four methods: it makes a new set and adds all those values -- either directly or indirectly.

So the difference is that for `s4`, at compile time, Python creates a constant `frozenset`. Presumably, when sets are created from frozensets at runtime, they just keep the same order (in this version at least).

See what happens if you make a set using the set display that can't be constructed from a constant:

```
>>> dis.dis('s = 11; s1 = {1, 2, 3, s}')
  0           0 RESUME                   0

  1           2 LOAD_CONST               0 (11)
              4 STORE_NAME               0 (s)
              6 LOAD_CONST               1 (1)
              8 LOAD_CONST               2 (2)
             10 LOAD_CONST               3 (3)
             12 LOAD_NAME                0 (s)
             14 BUILD_SET                4
             16 STORE_NAME               1 (s1)
             18 RETURN_CONST             4 (None)
>>> s = 11
>>> {1, 2, 3, s}
{11, 1, 2, 3}
```

This set too has to be constructed at run time, even though you're using the `{...}` syntax.

**TL;DR:** Probably the difference between sets constructed at compile time versus sets constructed during runtime.