# removing duplicates from nested list

Tags: python, list

I have a list of lists and want to remove duplicates from it. I have a way to work but it looks ugly and I'm not sure if there's a better way to do it.

```
a_list = [[1,2],[2,3],[1,2]]
print [list(tup) for tup in set([tuple(x) for x in a_list])]
```

which prints:

```
[[1,2],[2,3]]
```

which is what I want. I'm using small lists for this, so am not concerned with speed but am interested in if there is a nicer way to do this.

Comment: Similar question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3724551/python-uniqueness-for-list-of-lists

Answer (score 1):

You can make it a little shorter:

```
print list(set(tuple(x) for x in a_list))
```

Output:

```
[(1, 2), (2, 3)]
```

If you're not so worried about the display format, then simply leave off the outermost **list** conversion, giving:

```
set([(1, 2), (2, 3)])
```

---

I ran a timer on the three answers given so far, using /usr/shar/dict/words as the second part of each tuple, a simple **1** for the first element.  The file has nearly half a million (479,829) words.

0.517719984055 list->set->list (your original code)
1.30243611336  list->set->map  (tmajest's suggestion)
???            build new list  (Salman's suggestion)

The last one has not finished in over 6 minutes of run time.  **top** does show that it still has full use of one CPU.

Comment: This makes a list with tuples inside. I want it to be a list nested with lists.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> a_list=[[1,2],[2,3],[1,2]]
>>> newlist=[]
>>> for each in a_list:
        if each not in newlist:
            newlist.append(each)


>>> newlist
[[1, 2], [2, 3]]
```

Make a new empty list. If any list from a_list is not present in newlist, append it to newlist. Hope this helps. :)

Answer (score 0):

If the end result must be lists, then there's not really a shorter way.  You can use map instead of list comprehensions if you want:

```
list(map(list, set(map(tuple, a_list))))
```