# Unique values in a list of lists in Python

Tags: python, list, unique

I have a list of lists as following:

```
G = [[1,2,3],[2,3,5],[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[4,5,6]]
```

How can I find count of unique lists in G?

Comment: is the list always with three integers or this is a simple idea and in theory it can be of a random number of integers?

Comment: It is always have the same number of values.

Comment: This should help you `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3724551/python-uniqueness-for-list-of-lists`

Comment: This only give unique lists. How can I find number of times that each appeared in G?

Comment: Change lists to tuples and use collections.Counter ... but thats another questions. For both of wich you showed no code at all and no put no effort in it., What code _you_ came up with?

Comment: `unique_data = [list(x) for x in set(tuple(x) for x in G)]; len(unique_data)` for count

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the count of each sublist, the easiest way is to convert them to tuples and feed them to a [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter).

```
from collections import Counter

G = [[1,2,3],[2,3,5],[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[4,5,6]]

print(Counter(map(tuple, G)))
# Counter({(1, 2, 3): 2, (4, 5, 6): 2, (2, 3, 5): 1})
```

You need the conversion to tuples because lists are not hashable, and `Counter` uses a dictionary internally, which requires the keys to be hashable.