# how to get unique values from a python list of list?

Tags: python

for example,

```py
a = [[1, 2], [2, 3], [1, 2]]
```

I need it to be

```py
a = [[1, 2], [2, 3]]
```

since [1, 2] is duplicated.

set cannot be used because it did not accept a mutable object. and I know changing list to a tuple works. But is there a clean way if I want to keep them as lists? (not using numpy array)

Comment: What is unclean about converting to tuple then using a set? Seems pretty clean to me.

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-get-unique-values-list/amp/

Comment: Someone already had this problem! Is [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3724551/python-uniqueness-for-list-of-lists) helpful to you? 
c:

Comment: If you want to maintain order, `list(map(list, dict.fromkeys(map(tuple, a))))`

Comment: @spaghEddie Yes. I searched but I did not find that. thanks.

Comment: This is not the most efficient, but you can do `b = [x for i,x in enumerate(a) if x not in a[:i]]`

Comment: Is there any _reason_ why you want to keep them as lists? If not, it reads more like a useless puzzle that most people will not want to spend time trying to answer. Any time a restriction is introduced in the question that clearly prevents the optimal and natural solution, I wonder why anyone would ask "how to eat soup without spoons (or drinking it)" — just use the dang spoon. :) "I have a metal and plastic allergy so I can't use spoons" makes the question so much better.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this

```py
a = [a[i] for i in range(len(a)) if a.index(a[i]) == i]
```

Which includes an item in a only if it's the first occurence

Comment: this is extremely inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

First, you can transform your list of lists into a list of tuples:

```py
a = [tuple(l) for l in a]
```

Then, you can transform `a` into a `set`:

```py
>>> set(a)
set([(1, 2), (2, 3)])
```

Comment: I'm assuming OP isn't looking for that solution as it was mentioned in the question itself.